# PMF of a uniformly random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X, Y)$ be a point uniformly chosen from the set
$\{(k/N,l/N): 1≤k,l≤N\}$, for $k,l,N\in\mathbb{N}$.

Calculate the probability mass function of the random variable $Z = X + Y$.

I've been stuck with this question for quite some time now and haven't been able to do any progress.
I've tried to to first calculate which values $Z$ might take, but I don't seem to be able to come to any answers. The only thing I can think of is that $Z$ takes values in the set $\{\frac{k+l}{N}:1≤k,l≤N\}$, but this doesn't take me anywhere.
Apart from that I haven't been able to do anything else.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried, where are you stuck. please edit to include your attempt.

Comment: Think in how many ways you can get a sum of the form $\frac{m}{N}=\frac{k}{N}+\frac{l}{N}$ for various $m=2,3,\ldots,2N$. Each of those ways comes with probability $\frac{1}{N^2}$.

Comment: I think that I understand the $m=2,3,...,2N$ part, but how do get to the $\frac{1}{N^2}$?

Comment: @CF_Num2 Because by uniformity there are $N^2$ equiprobable outcomes for $(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints:*

- X and Y are independent.
- $P(Z=z) = P(X+Y=z) = \sum_{x_i} P(X=x_i, Y=z-x_i)$

Comment: Sorry but how are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: P(X=x0, Y=y0) = 1/N^2, P(X=x0) = 1/N, and P(Y=y0) = 1/N

Comment: I see thank you! Can you please explain how $P(X=x,Y=x)=1/N^2$ and $P(X=x)=P(Y=y)=1/N$?

Comment: P(X = x, Y = y) is the probability that point (x, y) is chosen. Since there are a total of N^2 points, and points are uniformly chosen it implies each point has an equal probability of being chosen. Therefore, P(X = x, Y = y) = 1/N^2. Similar logic for P(X = x) and P(Y = y).